# How to make a custom clickable by index?

Tags: java, android

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) and trying to make the profile photo's and the pictures posted in the post clickable.

If you visit the link you can see what it basically what it looks like.

Depending on the id of the image, I wanted to venture to a different activity. 
Here's what I've discovered that confusing me so much.

I've created a JSON file and saved it into a Dynamic Web Page.

"id": 1,
            "name": "Mark",

"id": 2,
                "name": "Tom",

The method (name is a textview):

```
name.setText(item.getName());
```

makes the name text view the "name" field from the JSON file.

The method:

```
name.setText(Integer.toString(item.getId()));
```

makes the name text view the "id" field from the JSON file.

What's crazy is that the values returned are a string and int variable.

So if if try

```
if (item.getId() == 1) {

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(context, NameActivity.class);
    myIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent1);
}

if (item.getId() == 2) {

    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(context, NameActivitySecondAttempt.class);
    myIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent2);
}
```

Unfortunately, the if statement doesn't understand the different values for "name" or "id".

I have these if statements in the `OnClickListener` for the two views that I'm trying to click on. See the extended code below.

profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Heres some XML

```
 <com.pm.pmv5.listviewfeed.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />

  <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>
```

When the page loads the numbers or names will correctly show up in the right spot. But the i can't travel to a separate particular activity according to thats posts's name or number.

Can some one help me.

```
////// this doesn't work either //////

switch (item.getId()) {

            case 1:

                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(context, NameActivity.class);
                myIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myIntent1);

                break;

            case 2:

                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(context, StartMenuV1.class);
                myIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myIntent2);

                break;

            case 3:

                Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(context, StartMenuV2.class);
                myIntent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myIntent3);

                break;
            }
        }

////// this doesn't work either //////
```

Here's How I've adjusted the class.. from the tutorial. why don't you try to download the project. Change the FeedListAdapter class with the code above. It takes 10 minutes. You'll be able to click on the image, but the value of `item.getId()` isn't consistent. Also don't forget to change the xml focusable and colonel values to true. Thanks for your help.

```
package com.pm.pmv5.listviewfeed.adapter;

import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.pm.pmv5.R;
import com.pm.pmv5.listviewfeed.FeedImageView;
import com.pm.pmv5.listviewfeed.app.AppController;
import com.pm.pmv5.listviewfeed.data.FeedItem;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.BoardActivity;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.BoardActivity2;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.BoardActivity3;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.NameActivity;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.StartMenuV1;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.StartMenuV2;
import com.pm.pmv5.takeover.StartMenuV3;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

    Context context;
    baZOOKA heyNOW;
    FeedItem item;
    String nueSELECTOR;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    NetworkImageView profilePic;
    FeedImageView feedImageView;
    TextView name;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        context = AppController.getInstance();

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        item = feedItems.get(position);

        // name.setText(item.getName());

        final int ok234 = feedItems.indexOf(1);
        int index = feedItems.indexOf("papa"); // index = 2

        // name.setText(Integer.toString(ok234));

        nueSELECTOR = Integer.toString(item.getId());

        name.setText(nueSELECTOR);
        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {

            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (item.getId() != 1) {

                    name.setText(item.getName());

                }

                if (item.getId() == 2) {

                    // name.setText(item.getName());

                }

            }
        });

        feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch (item.getId()) {

                case 1:

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cameraflash);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();

                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(context, NameActivity.class);
                    myIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent1);

                    break;

                case 2:

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cameraflash);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();

                    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(context, StartMenuV1.class);
                    myIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent2);

                    break;
                case 3:

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cameraflash);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();

                    Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(context, StartMenuV2.class);
                    myIntent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent3);

                    break;
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v2.getId()) {
        case R.id.profilePic:

            break;
        case R.id.feedImage1:

            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question, exactly what you're expecting, and what is happening that you don't expect.

Comment: @DanielNugent when i click on the profile picture or #1, i want to go to activity#1.. when press profile picture#2 i want to go to activity#2

Comment: You'll have to be more specific... where exactly in the code are the unexpected things happening?  Point out the exact line of code, what you expect to happen, and what you don't understand about what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Either debug and step through the code, or add some logging to see what's happening.

Every time you want to use `item.getId()`, just add some code like this:

```
int id = item.getId();
Log.d("MyApp", "item ID is: " + id);
```

Comment: when you scroll up and down the list view.. the value of "id" will change. thats the issue. @danielnugent